# Atom Regex a-z matches all text characters

Tags: regex, webstorm, atom-editor

I have this test string

`Hello Dog`

When I use atom regex matcher for `[a-z]`,

It returns all characters and not just the lower case ones. (elloog)

I need it to only match the lower case letters. Is the atom regex library different somehow? The same outcome happens in WebStorm...

Comment: Well .. in WebStorm you have "Match Case" option... With that option enabled and `[a-z]+` as pattern it will match `hello` but not `Hello` (only `ello` part of it).

Comment: yup. that was it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Atom, as in many other text editors, the *Match Case* is present as a separate option changing the way regex matching works.

If it is switched off, the `[a-z]` regex is case insensitive and matches uppercase ASCII letters, too.

Check this option to make matching case sensitive.